# Azure Data Factory webhook execution times out instead of relaying errors

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-data-factory, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I've attempted to set up a simple webhook execution in Azure Data Factory (v2), calling a simple (parameter-less) webhook for an Azure Automation Runbook I set up.

From the Azure Portal, I can see that the webhook is being executed and my runbook is being run, so far so good. The runbook is (currently) returning an error within 1 minute of execution - but that's fine, I also want to test failure scenarios.

**Problem**:
Data Factory doesn't seem to be 'seeing' the error result and spins until the timeout (10 minutes) elapses. When I kick off a debug run of the pipeline, I get the same - a timeout and no error result.

*Update*: I've fixed the runbook and it's now completing successfully, but Data Factory is still timing out and is not seeing the success response either.

Here is a screenshot of the setup:

[image]

And here is the portal confirming that the webhook is being run by azure data factory, and is completing in under a minute:

[image]

WEBHOOKDATA JSON is:

```
{"WebhookName":"Start CAMS VM","RequestBody":"{\r\n \"callBackUri\": \"https://dpeastus.svc.datafactory.azure.com/dataplane/workflow/callback/f7c...df2?callbackUrl=AAEAFF...0927&shouldReportToMonitoring=True&activityType=WebHook\"\r\n}","RequestHeader":{"Connection":"Keep-Alive","Expect":"100-continue","Host":"eab...ddc.webhook.eus2.azure-automation.net","x-ms-request-id":"7b4...2eb"}}
```

So as far as I can tell, things should be in place to pick up on the result (success of failure). Hopefully someone who's done this before knows what I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had assumed that Azure would automatically notify the ADF "callBackUri" with the result once the runbook completed or errored out (since they take care of 99% of the scaffolding without requiring a line of code).

It turns out that is not the case, and anyone wishing to execute a runbook from ADF will have to manually extract the callBackUri from the Webhookdata input parameter, and POST the result to it when done.

I haven't nailed this down yet, since the [Microsoft tutorial sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) I've found have a bad habit of taking screenshots of the code that does this rather than providing the code itself:

[image]

I guess I'll come back and edit this once I have it figured out.

---

**EDIT** I ended up implementing this by leaving my original Webhook untouched, and creating a "wrapper"/helper/utility Runbook that will execute an arbitrary webhook, and relay its status to ADF once it's complete.

Here's the full code I ended up with, in case it helps someone else. It's meant to be generic:

**Setup / Helper Functions**

```bsh
param
(
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [object] $WebhookData
)

Import-Module -Name AzureRM.resources
Import-Module -Name AzureRM.automation

# Helper function for getting the current running Automation Account Job
# Inspired heavily by: https://github.com/azureautomation/runbooks/blob/master/Utility/ARM/Find-WhoAmI
<#
    Queries the automation accounts in the subscription to find the automation account, runbook and resource group that the job is running in.
    AUTHOR: Azure/OMS Automation Team
#>
Function Find-WhoAmI {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param()
    Begin { Write-Verbose ("Entering {0}." -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand) }
    Process {
        # Authenticate
        $ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
        Add-AzureRmAccount `
            -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Write-Verbose
        Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $ServicePrincipalConnection.SubscriptionID | Write-Verbose 
        # Search all accessible automation accounts for the current job
        $AutomationResource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType Microsoft.Automation/AutomationAccounts
        $SelfId = $PSPrivateMetadata.JobId.Guid
        foreach ($Automation in $AutomationResource) {
            $Job = Get-AzureRmAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $Automation.ResourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $Automation.Name -Id $SelfId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Job))) {
                return $Job
            }
            Write-Error "Could not find the current running job with id $SelfId"
        }
    }
    End { Write-Verbose ("Exiting {0}." -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand) }
}

Function Get-TimeStamp {    
    return "[{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)    
}
```

**My Code**

```bsh
### EXPECTED USAGE ###
# 1. Set up a webhook invocation in Azure data factory with a link to this Runbook's webhook
# 2. In ADF - ensure the body contains { "WrappedWebhook": "<your url here>" }
#    This should be the URL for another webhook.
# LIMITATIONS:
# - Currently, relaying parameters and authentication credentials is not supported,
#    so the wrapped webhook should require no additional authentication or parameters.
# - Currently, the callback to Azure data factory does not support authentication,
#    so ensure ADF is configured to require no authentication for its callback URL (the default behaviour)

# If ADF executed this runbook via Webhook, it should have provided a WebhookData with a request body.
if (-Not $WebhookData) {
    Write-Error "Runbook was not invoked with WebhookData. Args were: $args"
    exit 0
}
if (-Not $WebhookData.RequestBody) {
    Write-Error "WebhookData did not contain a ""RequestBody"" property. Data was: $WebhookData"
    exit 0
}
$parameters = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody)
# And this data should contain a JSON body containing a 'callBackUri' property.
if (-Not $parameters.callBackUri) {
    Write-Error 'WebhookData was missing the expected "callBackUri" property (which Azure Data Factory should provide automatically)'
    exit 0
}
$callbackuri = $parameters.callBackUri

# Check for the "WRAPPEDWEBHOOK" parameter (which should be set up by the user in ADF)
$WrappedWebhook = $parameters.WRAPPEDWEBHOOK
if (-Not $WrappedWebhook) {
    $ErrorMessage = 'WebhookData was missing the expected "WRAPPEDWEBHOOK" peoperty (which the user should have added to the body via ADF)'
    Write-Error $ErrorMessage
}
else
{
    # Now invoke the actual runbook desired
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Invoking Webhook Request at: $WrappedWebhook"
    try {    
        $OutputMessage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $WrappedWebhook -UseBasicParsing -Method POST
    } catch {
        $ErrorMessage = ("An error occurred while executing the wrapped webhook $WrappedWebhook - " + $_.Exception.Message)
        Write-Error -Exception $_.Exception
    }
    # Output should be something like: {"JobIds":["<JobId>"]}
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Response: $OutputMessage"    
    $JobList = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $OutputMessage).JobIds
    $JobId = $JobList[0]
    $OutputMessage = "JobId: $JobId"         

    # Get details about the currently running job, and assume the webhook job is being run in the same resourcegroup/account
    $Self = Find-WhoAmI
    Write-Output "Current Job '$($Self.JobId)' is running in Group '$($Self.ResourceGroupName)' and Automation Account '$($Self.AutomationAccountName)'"
    Write-Output "Checking for Job '$($JobId)' in same Group and Automation Account..."

    # Monitor the job status, wait for completion.
    # Check against a list of statuses that likely indicate an in-progress job
    $InProgressStatuses = ('New', 'Queued', 'Activating', 'Starting', 'Running', 'Stopping')
    # (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/get-azautomationjob?view=azps-4.1.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-3.7.0)  
    do {
        # 1 second between polling attempts so we don't get throttled
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        try { 
            $Job = Get-AzureRmAutomationJob -Id $JobId -ResourceGroupName $Self.ResourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $Self.AutomationAccountName
        } catch {
            $ErrorMessage = ("An error occurred polling the job $JobId for completion - " + $_.Exception.Message)
            Write-Error -Exception $_.Exception
        }
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Polled job $JobId - current status: $($Job.Status)"
    } while ($InProgressStatuses.Contains($Job.Status))

    # Get the job outputs to relay to Azure Data Factory
    $Outputs = Get-AzureRmAutomationJobOutput -Id $JobId -Stream "Any" -ResourceGroupName $Self.ResourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $Self.AutomationAccountName
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Outputs from job: $($Outputs | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)"
    $OutputMessage = $Outputs.Summary
    Write-Output "Summary ouput message: $($OutputMessage)"
}

# Now for the entire purpose of this runbook - relay the response to the callback uri.
# Prepare the success or error response as per specifications at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity#additional-notes
if ($ErrorMessage) {
    $OutputJson = @"
{
    "output": { "message": "$ErrorMessage" },
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": {
        "ErrorCode": "Error",
        "Message": "$ErrorMessage"
    }
}
"@
} else {
    $OutputJson = @"
{
    "output": { "message": "$OutputMessage" },
    "statusCode": 200
}
"@
}
Write-Output "Prepared ADF callback body: $OutputJson"
# Post the response to the callback URL provided
$callbackResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $callbackuri -UseBasicParsing -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $OutputJson

Write-Output "Response was relayed to $callbackuri"
Write-Output ("ADF replied with the response: " + ($callbackResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Compress))
```

At a high-level, steps I've taken are to:

1. Execute the "main" Webhook - get back a "Job Id"
2. Get the current running job's "context" (resource group and automation account info) so that I can poll the remote job.
3. Poll the job until it is complete
4. Put together either a "success" or "error" response message in the format that Azure Data Factory expects.
5. Invoke the ADF callback.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking, I created a secondary approach to the above solution - one that executes a Runbook (with parameters) from a Webhook, rather than a invoking a nested Webhook. This has a couple of benefits:

- Parameters can be passed through to the Runbook (rather than requiring parameters to be baked-into a new Webhook.
- A Runbook from another Azure Automation Account / Resource Group can be invoked.
- There's no need to poll the status of the job, since the `Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook` commandlet has a `-Wait` parameter.

Here's the code:

```bsh
param
(
    # Note: While "WebhookData" is the only root-level parameter (set by Azure Data Factory when it invokes this webhook)
    #       The user should ensure they provide (via the ADF request body) these additional properties required to invoke the runbook:
    #       - RunbookName
    #       - ResourceGroupName (TODO: Can fill this in by default if not provided)
    #       - AutomationAccountName (TODO: Can fill this in by default if not provided)
    #       - Parameters (A nested dict containing parameters to forward along)
    [Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
    [object] $WebhookData
)

Import-Module -Name AzureRM.resources
Import-Module -Name AzureRM.automation

Function Get-TimeStamp {    
    return "[{0:yyyy-MM-dd} {0:HH:mm:ss}]" -f (Get-Date)    
}

# If ADF executed this runbook via Webhook, it should have provided a WebhookData with a request body.
if (-Not $WebhookData) {
    Write-Error "Runbook was not invoked with WebhookData. Args were: $args"
    exit 0
}
if (-Not $WebhookData.RequestBody) {
    Write-Error "WebhookData did not contain a ""RequestBody"" property. Data was: $WebhookData"
    exit 0
}
$parameters = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody)
# And this data should contain a JSON body containing a 'callBackUri' property.
if (-Not $parameters.callBackUri) {
    Write-Error 'WebhookData was missing the expected "callBackUri" property (which Azure Data Factory should provide automatically)'
    exit 0
}
$callbackuri = $parameters.callBackUri

# Check for required parameters, and output any errors.
$ErrorMessage = ''
$RunbookName = $parameters.RunbookName
$ResourceGroupName = $parameters.ResourceGroupName
$AutomationAccountName = $parameters.AutomationAccountName
if (-Not $RunbookName) {
    $ErrorMessage += 'WebhookData was missing the expected "RunbookName" property (which the user should have added to the body via ADF)`n'
} if (-Not $ResourceGroupName) {
    $ErrorMessage += 'WebhookData was missing the expected "ResourceGroupName" property (which the user should have added to the body via ADF)`n'
} if (-Not $AutomationAccountName) {
    $ErrorMessage += 'WebhookData was missing the expected "AutomationAccountName" property (which the user should have added to the body via ADF)`n'
} if ($ErrorMessage) {
    Write-Error $ErrorMessage
} else {
    # Set the current automation connection's authenticated account to use for future Azure Resource Manager cmdlet requests.
    # TODO: Provide the user with a way to override this if the target runbook doesn't support the AzureRunAsConnection
    $ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
    Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint | Write-Verbose
    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $ServicePrincipalConnection.SubscriptionID | Write-Verbose 

    # Prepare the properties to pass on to the next runbook - all provided properties exept the ones specific to the ADF passthrough invocation
    $RunbookParams = @{ }
    if($parameters.parameters) {
        $parameters.parameters.PSObject.Properties | Foreach { $RunbookParams[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
        Write-Output "The following parameters will be forwarded to the runbook: $($RunbookParams | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)"
    }

    # Now invoke the actual runbook desired, and wait for it to complete
    Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Invoking Runbook '$($RunbookName)' from Group '$($ResourceGroupName)' and Automation Account '$($AutomationAccountName)'"
    try {    
        # Runbooks have this nice flag that let you wait on their completion (unlike webhook-invoked)
        $Result = Start-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -Wait -Name $RunbookName -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName –Parameters $RunbookParams
    } catch {
        $ErrorMessage = ("An error occurred while invoking Start-AzAutomationRunbook - " + $_.Exception.Message)
        Write-Error -Exception $_.Exception
    }
    # Digest the result to be relayed to ADF
    if($Result) {
        Write-Output "$(Get-TimeStamp) Response: $($Result | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)"
        $OutputMessage = $Result.ToString()
    } elseif(-Not $ErrorMessage) {
        $OutputMessage = "The runbook completed without errors, but the result was null."
    }
}

# Now for the entire purpose of this runbook - relay the response to the callback uri.
# Prepare the success or error response as per specifications at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-webhook-activity#additional-notes
if ($ErrorMessage) {
    $OutputJson = @{
        output = @{ message = $ErrorMessage }
        statusCode = 500
        error = @{
            ErrorCode = "Error"
            Message = $ErrorMessage
        }
    } | ConvertTo-Json -depth 2
} else {
    $OutputJson = @{
        output = @{ message = $OutputMessage }
        statusCode = 200
    } | ConvertTo-Json -depth 2
}
Write-Output "Prepared ADF callback body: $OutputJson"
# Post the response to the callback URL provided
$callbackResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $callbackuri -UseBasicParsing -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $OutputJson

Write-Output "Response was relayed to $callbackuri"
Write-Output ("ADF replied with the response: " + ($callbackResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Compress))
```